# Delete the call/sms log history for specific numbers?

Tags: android

in my app i want to delete the sms's/calls of specific numbers i am new to android can any body help me

Answer (score 1):

For calls: use content provider described here: http://d.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html

I'm not sure about SMS.

Comment: i don't want to delete a contact number but i want to delete calls from call log for specified user for eg Delete all incoming calls/sms for contact name joe from incoming call list

Comment: Right, use content provider described here: http://d.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html for calls, I'm not sure about SMS

Answer (score 0):

I use this to delete a particular message from the SMS inbox:

```
    //Delete entire SMS thread.
    getContext().getContentResolver().delete(
        Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/" + threadID), 
        null, 
        null);

    //Delete single message.
    getContext().getContentResolver().delete(
            Uri.parse("content://sms/" + messageID),
            null, 
            null);
```

These work for me given a valid Thread ID or Message ID.